# Google Apps Script - Only send emails in current year

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

In our college we loan out Chromebooks for the duration of students time here, we're pretty slack in contacting the students to request them back so after they leave we tend to play catch up and have to contact them to bring them back.

The length of time the students stay varies between 1 and 3 years. I want to create a log sheet where we can keep track of these students and what devices they borrow. Then in the month prior to them leaving, automatically send an email to say they need to return their Chromebook to us.

In my sheet we have an 'Expected return date' which we only input the year that they are due to leave since each students actual leave data is different depending on their subjects. The idea would be that I would set a trigger to run before on a day before any student leaves the college.

I'm very new to scripting but so far I have built a script (using a lot of Google searching, copying what I've found online and tinkering) where it will look through the Sheet, find any rows of data without the words 'EMAIL_SENT' in them and send an email. If it shows 'EMAIL_SENT' it skips them. When I say I'm new, this has taken me a week to get to this point.

I will add triggers in for it to only run once per year however I only want it to send emails to the students who would be leaving this current year, whatever order they are in within the sheet. Is there a way I can get it to call the current year, look for the expected return date and only send if it is that same year?

My script so far is below.

[image]

Hope this makes sense.

```
// This constant is written in column I for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';

/**
 * Sends non-duplicate emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails2(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // first row of data to process
  var numRows = 1000; // number of rows to process
    // Fetch the range of cells A2:B4
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1,9);
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues ();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[3]; // fourth column
    var recipient = row[0]; // first column
    var asset = row[6]; // seventh column
    var loanDate = row [7] + ""; // seventh column
    var returnDate = row[8]; // ninth column
    var message = 'Hi ' + recipient + '. \n\n' + 'On ' + loanDate + ' you borrowed Chromebook ' + asset + ' from Learning Support. \n\n' + 'Since you are soon to leave the college, we require this Chromebook to be returned to the IT Office before the 30/06/' + returnDate + '. \n\n' + 'Kind regards,\n\n' + 'IT Services';
    var emailSent = row[2]; // third column
    if (emailSent !=EMAIL_SENT) { //prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = 'Chromebook Loan';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 10).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Many of you your array indexes seem incorrect.

Comment: They all work though, maybe my labels are incorrect, I'll update those.

Comment: What do you mean by "call the current year"? You can use `(new Date()).getYear()` to get the current year and compare that with your year value. Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

You should just add a variable which gets the current year and afterwards add a new condition in your `if` which checks the two of them.

So the new variable:

```
var yearNow = newDate.getFullYear();
```

And the `if`:

```
if (emailSent !=EMAIL_SENT && returnDate == yearNow)
```

For adding the trigger which will run once a year you could use the following function:

```
function createTheTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmails2')
      .timeBased()
      .everyWeeks(52)
      .create();
}
```

The above function creates a trigger which will run every **52 weeks** which is approximately **1 year**.

Furthermore, I suggest you check the following links since they might be of help:

- [Working with Dates and Times Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates);
- [Installable Triggers Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable);
- [Script Service Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script).